# Is it possible to start a sibling Vagrant machine from within a guest?

Tags: vagrant

While setting up our automation environment, we are ending up at a point where we envision the following:

Our Jenkins server communicate with a Jenkins worker. This worker runs within a Vagrant machine. 
Then, the Jenkins worker would start different other Vagrant machines as builders, and restore them to a given snapshot when they are done building.

A complication with that is that the Jenkins worker, which is already a Vagrant guest machine on the physical host, should start another Vagrant guest machine directly on the host, not within itself (which would be both complicated and de-optimized with VirtualBox provider).

Is it possible?
If so, how?

Note: to clarify things, starting sibling containers from within a container is possible with Docker, following the approach in this blog post:
http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/ (see section *The solution*)

**Edit (some rationale):**

We are aware it is possible to achieve the sibling container startup with Docker (see provided link), yet we cannot use Docker because the VM we need to run as builders have to be both OS X and Windows.

Some proposal could be to have the Jenkins worker be the host environment, from where it will trivial to spawn Vagrant builders. Yet, we strongly prefer to avoid that for several reason:

- Containerised Jenkins worker allow for the usual maintenance benefits: easy migration, scaling, reset
- Security and isolation: if the worker is compromised, we really don't want it to be the physical machine that supports many other critical processes.

Comment: It would probably be better to orchestrate this from outside Vagrant somehow. That being said, that new Kafka messaging between workers might make this easier when it finishes, or you could just try running Jenkins on Kubernetes right now, which may also make all of this easier.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thank you for your comment. We are not aware of what you refer to with *Kafka messaging between workers*, could you please provide some pointers to get us started? Also, what could *Jenkins on Kubernetes* do to help with starting Vagrant builders from within a VM worker, but to run them on the same host ?

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant is not designed for this and it is not possible to do that.

As you also pointed out, Docker is better for the job but DiD might be overkill, instead use your own host to start a Jenkins server inside a Docker container. Pass host's Docker socket to this container and whenever you need a Jenkins worker start a new container inside your Jenkins server.

All the containers will be directly running on the host and it will be easier to manage.

See below as a starting point https://getintodevops.com/blog/the-simple-way-to-run-docker-in-docker-for-ci

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the link we provided for reference is explaining exactly what you describe. Yet, we are looking how to achieve that with Vagrant, not Docker, because the VMs we need to start are OS X and Windows (on a Mac physical server). That might be impossible at the moment, but that is a serious complication for us.